# How do i make my nav-bar items stretch across the screen responsively

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wanting items in my nav bar to stretch across the width of the screen when on lets say a laptop, and go one-under another when on a phone.

Also, I don't like how my items are pushed over to the left , i want them to be equally spaced across the screen.

HTML:

```html
<!-- Logo -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="assets/images/BridgmanLogo.png" alt="Logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- SLIDER -->
<header class="container-fluid intro-slider">
  <div class="bg-slider-wrapper">
    <div id="bg-slider" class="flexslider bg-slider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide slide-1">
          <div class="push-text-slide"></div>
          <section class="home-promo">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h2 class="titlepro">
                <span class="upper">Welcome to</span>
                <span class="middle"><strong>Bridgman IBC Ltd</strong></span>
                <span class="bottom">An Example Tag Line Goes Here</span></h2>
              <a href="" class="btn promo-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><i></i>Shop</a>
            </div>
          </section>
        </li>
        <li class="slide slide-2">
          <div class="push-text-slide"></div>
          <section class="home-promo">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h2 class="titlepro">
                <span class="upper">Welcome to</span>
                <span class="middle"><strong>Bridgman IBC Ltd</strong></span>
                <span class="bottom">An Example Tag Line Goes Here</span></h2>
              <a href="" class="btn promo-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><i></i>Shop</a>
            </div>
          </section>
        </li>
        <li class="slide slide-3">
          <div class="push-text-slide"></div>
          <section class="home-promo">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h2 class="titlepro">
                <span class="upper">Welcome to</span>
                <span class="middle"><strong>Bridgman IBC Ltd</strong></span>
                <span class="bottom">An Example Tag Line Goes Here</span></h2>
              <a href="" class="btn promo-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><i></i>Shop</a>
            </div>
          </section>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Specifying</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Market Sectors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Shop</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that much space can be accommodated horizontally in smaller devices without breaking into new lines.

Comment: According to bootstrap docs **Justified navbar nav links are currently not supported.**.  And regarding collapsing: "The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is `768px`"

Comment: It'll take a lot of overriding. If you don't want default bootstrap nav behavior, I think it's better to use a separate menu plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there are some changes you should do:

1. Read the css I added. I'm using flex to stretch the item equally in the menu.
2. Remove the `.container` div to stretch the navigation to the width of the window.
3. Remove the `.navbar-right` class from the navigation you don't need it.

**I didn't take care about the mobile** I'm sure you know how to do all those changes in desktop only using media query.

```css
.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav, .navbar-nav>li {
  float:none !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display:flex;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!--<div class="container">-->
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">-->
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">Specifying</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">Market Sectors</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">Shop</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/wisuyi/edit?html,css

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use media queries to get responsive view.

```
.navbar-brand{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-brand ul li{
  width:20%; 
  /*Adjust the percent based on 100/number of items (Here it is 5)*/
  min-width:150px;
  /*Keep a minimum width such that the text does not overflow*/
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

/*Write media queries for Mobile and tablets*/
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .navbar-brand ul li{
     width:100%;
   }
}
```